# How to exclude directories with blanks via locate's PRUNEPATHS?

Tags: directory, locate

I would like to exclude some Windows folders on an NTFS mount from being indexed by `locate`. I'm familiar with the `PRUNEPATHS` syntax in `/etc/updatedb.conf`.  It is a white-space separated list of directory names.

My problem is that I want to exclude directories that contain white space themselves (e.g. `Program Files (x86)`).

I tried backslash escapes but that didn't work.

Comment: Which `locate` implementation you have? Some `locate`'s `updatedb` is a shell script. In that case see how it uses PRUNEPATHS, that may lead to a workaround.

Comment: I use `locate` (GNU findutils) 4.4.2.  Its `updatedb` is indeed a shell script (/usr/bin/updatedb.findutils).  I'll see what I can do from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `updatedb.sh` line 175 gives a hint:

> ```
> PRUNEREGEX=`echo $PRUNEPATHS|sed -e 's,^,\\\(^,' -e 's, ,$\\\)\\\|\\\(^,g' -e 's,$,$\\\),'`
> ```

There the `$PRUNEPATHS` is handled like plain text, the ' ' characters are replaced and no escaping is possible.

To ensure the space survives that line 175, you must denote it without explicitly mentioning it. The best way I know is to use `\s`, which means a whitespace character:

```
PRUNEPATHS='/path/to/Program\sFiles\s(x86)'
```

(That will also include tab and newline characters, but in this case will be fine for you.)

Another way is to set `$PRUNEREGEX` directly, as `updatedb` would do in line 175:

```
PRUNEREGEX='\(^/path/to/Program Files (x86)$\)'
```

There you separate multiple paths with `\|`, so space is not an issue anymore:

```
PRUNEREGEX='\(^/path/to/Program Files (x86)$\)\|\(^/foo/bar$\)'
```

Comment: The `\s` trick works but only with the `--prunepaths` option of the script not whe put in the conf file.  I'll probably make my own `PRUNEREGEX`. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly I only tested it with command line parameter and environment variable. Actually I was unable to find any evidence that `updatedb` uses `/etc/updatedb.conf`.